# AS3 - How can I change contents of all the same Movieclips runtime?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, swap, movieclip

So, basically, what I want to do is replace the contents of a sword MovieClip  that's inside a Player MovieClip already, and is animated, so it has multiple instances of the sword MovieClip across the Player MovieClip.

Can I somehow edit the contents of the sword MovieClip in actionscript so as all the sword MovieClips update and are changed?

What I want to achieve is just changing weapons of a character animation that doesn't require me to await every frame and removeChild() the previous weapon and addChild() the new one of every instance of the weapon.

Comment: Can you please show some code? I mean what you have tried so far?

Comment: What I currently have is 
    `var weaponName:String = "swordBasic1";
var weaponNameClass:Class = getDefinitionByName (weaponName) as Class;
var WeaponName=new weaponNameClass ;`


`if (PlayerCharMc.currentFrame!=5) {
   PlayerCharMc.WeaponMc.addChild(WeaponName);
  } else if (PlayerCharMc.currentFrame==5) {
   PlayerCharMc.LPunch.WeaponMc.addChild(WeaponName);
  }`


This basically pastes over the previous movieclip the new one, I haven't added removeChilds yet, but I understood that I won't get far with a flexible system. What I want to change is the movieclip in the library dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I'm getting it but Maybe you need a weapons event class
package WeaponEvents{
    import flash.events.Event;

```
[Event(name="sword1", type="event.sword1")]
[Event(name="sword2", type="event.sword2")] 


public class SwordEvent extends Event
{

    public static const SWORD_1 : String = "sword1";
    public static const SWORD_2 : String = "sword2";

    public var arg:*;

    public function SwordEvent(type:String, bubbles:Boolean = false, cancelable:Boolean = false, ... a:*) {
        super(type, bubbles, cancelable);
        arg = a;

    }
```

// Override clone
        override public function clone():Event{
            return new LoadEvent(type, bubbles, cancelable, arg);
        }
    }
 }

Just add the event to when your user chagnes weapons.

Comment: PS as long as you have strongly typed events and remove them when they are no longer needed you are not going to have to worry about the performance issues of generic events.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I haven't been able to get it working yet, though, but that is because of me neglecting anything related to classes and packages. I am making everything in one file, and I thought that code across multiple files was for bigger projects. Is this really foolish, as I don't know anything about packages, classes and importing these said classes?

Answer (score 0):

I'm in a similar boat as you. Except I have 30-50 bodyparts to cover, so I really can't go the brute force way.

If it's just sword that you want replace though, I assume in the animation it is on its own layer? Then a "cheap way" I found is:

1. Copy paste all frames in that layer (and only that layer) into another movieclip i.e. Sword1Swing.
2. Remove that layer (and only that layer) from your MC animation.
3. In yet another movie layer, put Sword1Swing on frame 1, Sword2Swing on frame 2, etc.
4. `MC.gotoAndStop("SwordSwing"); SwordMC.gotoAndStop("Sword1Swing");`
5. As long as you keep the .x and .y of the SwordMC synchronized with MC, the animation should always line up.
6. Hand often goes over the top of the sword, in which case... You can copy the hand too. Or the whole arm. Or you can custom shape your sword symbol's basic graphics in the library to match exactly with the empty spaces between fingers (copy and paste hand graphics in place to remove unwanted portions, then delete the hand graphics, then you'll have the perfect shape).

It's the ghetto way I know, I am very much in need of an actual efficient swapping. But this may help you to get through the project fast.